# NodeJS (Express.js) : How to make the Session global

Tags: node.js, session, express, global

I know that global vars are a bad practice in javascript and in programming overall, but i want to make my user session available throughout my express.js app, avoiding having to pass the session parameter all over, from my controllers to my models.

How can I best do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you really have to "pass the session parameter all over"? Can't you access session anywhere from `req.session`?

Comment: that means passing around `req` all over doesn't it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up solving this like so:

```
var appendLocalsToUseInViews = function(req, res, next)
{            
    //append request and session to use directly in views and avoid passing around needless stuff
    res.locals.session = req.session;
    next(null, req, res);
}
```

Then add it to the middleware:

```
app.use(appendLocalsToUseInViews);
```

Comment: Documentation [states](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.locals) that `res.locals` should be used to "set variables accessible in templates rendered with res.render". This may not be the proper way to achieve what OP asked for.

Answer (score -2):

if you really want to do this, add the request or session to the [global](http://nodejs.org/api/globals.html)-object of node though i would also not recommend this...

Comment: Obviously this won't work or is a gross simplification of doing something a bit more sophisticated. You would have many sessions active in parallel. The asking person wanted to access the right session within function calls. This would probably only work if node.js knows what session it is acting for and can expose that through API.